# Making a website with Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use Python in a website?

I want to make a website using some of my Python code, but can I do that?

Comment: Yes, I suggest looking at http://flask.pocoo.org/. But this question doesn't belong here, it's too broad.

Comment: I think every language that supports TCP listeners, or allows you to implement them, or allows you to write an IIS or Apache or OtherWebServerSoftware plugin can be used to build a website in. So I think the answer is "`Yes`" for everything but a handful of esoteric languages and batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple sites I tend to use [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) with [beaker](https://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for session handling and [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for database management. These along with few page templates and css ([bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) maybe?) can kick-start a new website fast

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python can be used for backend. There are different frameworks for it (for example I use Django).

For frontend you still need to use html/css/javascript.